# Finding people within a distance of x miles with graticule gem and Rails 3.1

Tags: google-maps-api-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, distance

I am using Graticule to find people within a distance of x miles from an event. I need to send mail to everyone who is within x miles of the event.

Here is my code :-

user.rb

```
def self.weekly_update
    @users = User.all
    @users.each do |u|
      @events = Event.all_with_distance([u.geo_lat, u.geo_lng]).where("start > ?", Time.zone.now).where("distance < 15")
      UsersMailer.weekly_mail(u.email, @events).deliver
    end
end

def self.all_with_distance(origin)
    distance_sql = sql_for_distance(origin)
    select("#{table_name}.*, #{distance_sql} AS distance").select("`locations`.`geo_lat`, `locations`.`geo_lng`, `locations`.`name` as location_name").joins(:location)
end
```

geo_search.rb

```
module GeoSearch
    def sql_for_distance(origin)
      Graticule::Distance::Spherical.to_sql(
        :latitude => origin[0],
        :longitude => origin[1],
        :latitude_column => "`locations`.`geo_lat`",
        :longitude_column => "`locations`.`geo_lng`",
        :units => :kilometers
      )
    end
  end
end
```

This is the error which I am getting :-

```
/usr/local/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.0/lib/rails/commands/runner.rb:49:in `eval': Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'distance' in 'where clause': SELECT events.*, (ACOS( SIN(RADIANS(26.8465108)) * SIN(RADIANS(`locations`.`geo_lat`)) + COS(RADIANS(26.8465108)) * COS(RADIANS(`locations`.`geo_lat`)) * COS(RADIANS(`locations`.`geo_lng`) - RADIANS(80.9466832)) ) * 6378.135)  AS distance, `locations`.`geo_lat`, `locations`.`geo_lng`, `locations`.`name` as location_name FROM `events` INNER JOIN `locations` ON `locations`.`id` = `events`.`location_id` WHERE (start > '2011-12-10 10:38:20') AND (distance < 15) (ActionView::Template::Error)
```

If I remove `.where("distance < 15")` to `.order("distance")` everything works fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In both standard SQL and the dialect supported by MySQL, [column aliases](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/problems-with-alias.html) can't be used in a `WHERE` clause; you must use the column. Here's what it would look like for your code, placing the call to `where` in `all_with_distance`:

```
select("#{table_name}.*, #{distance_sql} AS distance")
    .select("`locations`.`geo_lat`, `locations`.`geo_lng`, `locations`.`name` as location_name")
    .joins(:location)
    .where("#{distance_sql} < 50")
```

Comment: Note you can [format lines as code](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/) by indenting them four spaces. The "{}" button in the editor toolbar does this for you. Edit your answer and try it out. Click the orange question mark in the editor toolbar for more information and tips on formatting.

Comment: @outis Thanks for the suggestion, in future i will keep it in mind